# Do Cisco ACL need to be configured in both directions to allow traffic?

Tags: cisco, access-control-list

I'm not sure how Cisco ACL works on a SF300 managed switch.

I have the switch in L3 mode and with different VLANs configured.

Each VLAN has couple of ports in Access mode assigned to it.

For each VLAN, I wanted to apply some ACL rules. For example, one VLAN should only be able to access the internet to browse websites, so allowing ports 80 and 443.

The ACE rules I tried look like this:

```
permit tcp 10.0.100.0 0.0.0.255 any any www ace-priority 100335
permit tcp 10.0.100.0 0.0.0.255 any any 443 ace-priority 100355
```

But this alone will not let the clients access the web. To do that, I had to allow the traffic in opposite direction as well:

```
permit  tcp any www 10.0.100.0 0.0.0.255 any ace-priority 100375
permit  tcp any 443 10.0.100.0 0.0.0.255 any ace-priority 100395
```

Which is something I don't like because I want to only allow connections requested by the clients in the VLAN. I don't want to allow unsolicited connection from outside.

**So my question is whether there's a way to allow web access without having to use both sets of rules on this Cisco managed switch.**

My only guess is that what I try to achieve is not a job for a switch but instead for a firewall, which the SF300 is not. Or maybe I miss some keyword, like "established", which I found in some manuals but it doesn't seem to apply to the SF300 switch as there's no such keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SF300 has limited ACL capability, as you've discovered.  It only allows ACLs in the "inbound" direction on an interface.  So the only way to accomplish what you want is to also put an ACL on the Internet-facing VLAN interface.  This is the equivalent of the "established" keyword.

```
permit  tcp any match +ack 10.0.100.0 0.0.0.255 any
deny tcp any 10.0.100.0 0.0.0.255 any
permit ip any any
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Formally - yup, sure.
But the industry standard approach is to use only inbound ACLs, and allow everything outgoing. So if you'll decide to use this approach, you will have to define the `access-group` for incoming traffic only.

Comment: Care to cite this industry "standard?"

Comment: Nope. Why should I ? You either trust my word or get your own industry experience, and from your "care to cite" manner I can guess that your experience just started a few years back. Lol. If not months.

Comment: I would think that an industry standard would have lots of citeable sources. Unless by "industry standard," you mean "just my opinion."

Comment: Thats another illusion you will have to get rid of, honey.